# SQL Server Shared Lock on Select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I am querying a table in SQL Server DB that gets continuous inserts from other sources. The `SELECT` statement used to read the data from this table is used in my ETL job and it queries only a selected partition in the table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM REALTIMESRC 
WHERE PARTITION = '2018-11';
```

I understand that `SELECT` statement by default introduces a Shared Lock on the rows that it selects.

1. When this table gets inserts from other sources in the same partition where I am querying, does data insert get impacted due to my Select operation?
2. I am presuming that shared lock introduced by `Select` statement will be applicable at row table and doesn't apply to new inserts which happens in parallel. Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > I understand that SELECT statement by default introduces a shared lock on the rows that it selects.

That is correct, yes.

> > When this table gets inserts from other sources in the same partition 
> >     where I am querying, does data insert get impacted due to my `Select` operation?

No, since the insert only introduces new rows that you haven't selected, there shouldn't be any problem.

> > I am presuming that shared lock introduced by Select statement will be applicable at row table and doesn't apply to new inserts which happens in parallel.

Yes, that is correct - the `INSERT` and `SELECT` should work just fine in parallel.

There might be some edge cases where you could run into trouble:

- if the `INSERT` statement tries to insert more than 5000 rows in a single transaction, SQL Server might opt to *escalate* those 5000 individual locks into a **table-level** exclusive lock - at which point no more `SELECT` operations would be possible until the `INSERT` transaction completes